# white space get trimmed after adding custom tags in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, space

```
function sidebar(editor)
{   
    var selection = editor.getSelection();
    if(selection.getSelectedText()!="")
    {       
        var range = selection.getRanges();  
        var customNode = editor.document.createElement( 'cdl:sidebar' );
        var extractedContent = range[0].extractContents();
        customNode.append(extractedContent);
        var sidebarHolder = editor.document.createElement("sidebarHolder");
        sidebarHolder.append(customNode);
        var nodeHtml = sidebarHolder.getHtml();
        editor.insertHtml(nodeHtml+" ");        
    }  
    else {
        showErrorMessage("Selection is not proper");
    }   
}
```

This is my code.Whenever i select a single word like "Please" in "Please post comments or corrections" statement ,after adding tags Please.The space between "Please Post" get's trimmed.But when i select "Please "(word with space),the code works correctly.And , i want that tag should not visible in editor , it should be visible in source panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending html to ckeditor instance rather adding text.